# Finding characteristic curve of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The characteristic curves of PDE

> $(2x+u)u_x + (2y+u)u_y = u$

passing through $(1,1)$ for any arbitrary initial values prescribed on a non characteristic curve are given by:

1. $x=y$
2. $x^2 + y^2 = 2$
3. $x + y = 2$
4. $x^2 + y^2 - xy = 1$

It's a single select question, that is exactly one the above options is true which gives the characteristic curves.
Pardon if it seems trivial but I am not aware of the steps that shall be involved in solving this question. Kindly help out, thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you tell us how much you *do* know about characteristic curves to begin with.

Comment: I know to solve the Lagrange's Auxillary Equations. I was told it will be somehow used here. I suppose to learn the concept from this question if it gets answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comment you wrote : " I suppose to learn the concept from this question if it gets answered here". I think this is not a good idea. Taking the problem backward doesn't simplify the understanding. If you want learn from examples, better look at examples of direct solving of PDEs. They are a lot of examples fully solved on the forum.

Nevertheless I post a method of solving below. But I doubt that this will help you much to "understand the concept" as you say.

$$(2x+u)u_x+(2y+u)u_y=u $$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{2x+u}=\frac{dy}{2y+u}=\frac{du}{u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{2x+u}=\frac{du}{u}$ leading to :
$$\frac{x+u}{u^2}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{2y+u}=\frac{du}{u}$ leading to :
$$\frac{y+u}{u^2}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ is :
$$\Phi\left(\frac{x+u}{u^2}\:,\:\frac{y+u}{u^2}\right)=0$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

This is a method to solve a problem when a boundary condition is specified, allowing to determine the function $\Phi$. This is not the case of the present problem. Thus the above general solution is of no use.

To go further in the present case we note that they are a lot of characteristic equations dependant one from others which can be written in combining the two above ones. For example we look for some characteristic equations involving only $x$ and $y$ without $u$.

$\frac{c2}{c1}=\frac{y+u}{x+u}\quad\implies\quad u=\frac{c_2x-c_1y}{c_1-c_2}$

$c_1=\frac{x+u}{u^2}=\frac{x+\frac{c_2x-c_1y}{c_1-c_2}}{(\frac{c_2x-c_1y}{c_1-c_2})^2}\quad$ and after simplification :
$$(c_2x-c_1y)^2+(x-y)(c_2-c_1)=0$$
Now we look if among the four characteristic equations proposed in the multiple choice, one of them is consistent with $(c_2x-c_1y)^2+(x-y)(c_2-c_1)=0$ for some specific values of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

We observe that the cases 2,3,4  have a non nul constant term on the right. So they are rejected.

The case 1 : $\quad x=y\quad$ is convenient if we set $c_1=c_2$ . This is the expected choice.

Comment: Appreciate your effort. A small typo there in the last fraction of the auxiliary equation, it should be $\frac{du}{u}$

Comment: You are right there was a typo (now corrected).